# Elasticsearch OS X: Could not initialize class org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentFactory

Tags: macos, elasticsearch, homebrew

using ElasticSearch with Rails. (0.19.1)

After restart of my Mac all of a sudden it won't start anymore. Not sure what changed (did update Java recently)
I installed via homebrew, and after re-install same issue.

when I try and start it with:

```
elasticsearch -f -D es.config=/usr/local/Cellar/elasticsearch/0.19.1/config/elasticsearch.yml
```

I get this:

```
[2012-09-13 10:33:38,865][INFO ][node                     ] [Ulysses] {0.19.1}[3944]: initializing ...
[2012-09-13 10:33:38,873][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Ulysses] loaded [], sites []
[2012-09-13 10:33:40,381][ERROR][bootstrap                ] {0.19.1}: Initialization Failed ...
1) NoClassDefFoundError[Could not initialize class org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentFactory]2) StackOverflowError[null]
```

Can't find much on this error and really stuck now... 
Any tips much appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Most commonly you made a RAM update.
Change JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xss128k" to this: JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xss256k"

in /usr/local/Cellar/elasticsearch/0.19.x/bin/elasticsearch.in.sh

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Can you try and use a newer version of elasticsearch, it should fixed there (homebrew should have 0.19.9). Alternatively, the fix is simple and requires changing in the `elasticsearch.in.sh` file this line: `JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xss128k"` to this: `JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xss256k"`.

Comment: For some reason my homebrew only installed 0.19.0 - anyway your fix worked. Thank you!

Comment: People stumbling upon this answer, I hope you realize this is the creator of elastic search :D